# bootstrap upload file does not send multiple pics to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fileinputstream

[image]

I have a bootstrap file input. if i click the browse button and select multiple pics I am able to send the pics to controller but if I click browse button and select only 1 pic and then if I click browse button again and select another pic and I can only send one of the pics to my controller. Does anybody know the reason?

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attachments, new { type = "file", @class = "file", name = "file", multiple = "multiple" })
```

this code lets me add multiple pics by clicking browse button. without this code if I click the browse button select pic and if i click browse button and select another pic it would just replace the pic.it would not add second pic.

```
  $("#Attachments").fileinput({ uploadUrl: "/file-upload-batch/2"});
```

viewmodel

```
  public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Attachments { get; set; }
```

Comment: Because it overwrites your previous selection ? That is the browser behavior. Rite ?

Comment: Maybe, but i think hes asking how to fix it. :)

Comment: it is because it does not support form submission.